# Clojure: Using proxy and mutable fields

Tags: clojure

I'm using proxy in Clojure to extend a Java class.  I need to set a field in the superclass, how can i do this?  The code below doesn't work.

```
(proxy [BasicPlayer] []
  (open [url]
  (set! super/m_dataSource url)))
```

Comment: can you specify the visibility of this superclass field? public, protected or private ... because I think that if it's public or protected you will have access to this field from your proxy object

Comment: `(open [this url] (set! (.m_dataSource this) url))` ?

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin, your comment is actually a correct answer; it provided the answer for [my duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30060080/1455243).  I didn't know about `set!`.   (Granted, Matthew used `set!`, but I also didn't know that you could apply it in the way that you specified.)  Alex's answer is appropriate only for some situations.  If you add an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation for `proxy`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/proxy):

> Note that while method fns can
>   be provided to override protected methods, they have no other access
>   to protected members, nor to super, as these capabilities cannot be
>   proxied.

Sorry, but it sounds like you're out of luck. You can call protected superclass methods with `proxy-super`, but I think that's about it.

You might have better luck with `gen-class`. Something along the lines of:

```
(ns my.Player
  (:gen-class
   :extends BasicPlayer 
   :exposes {m_dataSource {:set -setDataSource}})

(defn -open [this url]
  (-setDataSource this url))
```