# Set inherited instance variable with proxy?

Tags: clojure

I know that it's possible to set an instance variable inherited from a Java class in Clojure with `gen-class` using the `:exposes` keyword.  Is there a way to set an inherited instance variable using `proxy`?

I'm rewriting some Java code in Clojure.  The Java source uses an anonymous extended class, so it seemed natural to try to use `proxy` in the Clojure version.  Here's the Java version (simplified):

```
yardPortrayal.setPortrayalForAll(new OvalPortrayal2D(){
    public void draw(Object object, Graphics2D graphics, DrawInfo2D info) {
        Student student = (Student)object;
        int agitationShade = (int) (student.getAgitation() * 255 / 10.0);
        paint = new Color(agitationShade, 0, 255 - agitationShade);
        super.draw(object, graphics, info);
    }
});
```

`paint` is a variable in a superclass, and it needs to be set before `super.draw()` is called.

Here's my Clojure version:

```
(.setPortrayalForAll yard-portrayal
                     (proxy [OvalPortrayal2D] []
                       (draw [student graphics info]
                         (let [agitation-shade (int (/ (* 255.0 (.getAgitation student)) 10.0))
                               color (Color. agitation-shade 0 (- 255 agitation-shade))]
                           ;; HOW TO SET INHERITED paint VAR TO color?
                           (proxy-super draw student graphics info)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for finding the duplicate question, folks.  Leon Grapenthin's comment there provided the answer to my question.  Perhaps he'll turn it into an official answer.